# the calculator doesnt calculate more than one numbers in the first number ,why?

Tags: java, swing

I am making a calculator program but it doesnt calculate the right side
if the right side is more than one number
like
99+1 it doesnt calculate this example
butif it was one number
like
9+1 then it will calculate it
and this problem is in the right side only

```
class ActionListeners implements ActionListener {

    @Override

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object o = e.getSource();
        int[] r = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        if (o == result) {

            String s = t1.getText();
            int indexno = s.indexOf('+');

            String s3 = s.substring(0, indexno);
            String s4 = s.substring(indexno);

            for (int b : r) {
                if (s.charAt(b) == '+') {
                    int n1 = Integer.parseInt(s3);
                    int n2 = Integer.parseInt(s4);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, n1 + n2);
                }
                if (s.length() < s.charAt(b)) {
                    break;
                }

            }
```

Comment: What do you think your condition `if (s.length() < s.charAt(b))` actually does?

Comment: because when the charAt(b) is bigger than the lenght of the characters it gives me an error so i break the loop

Comment: Well, all visible characters are stored as numbers over 30, so that condition will always be true. The condition stops your calculator from working, unless the + sign is found on the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: it works but it gives an exception

Comment: The exception is because of `for (int b : r) `. You probably want to rethink that part.

Comment: The problem you are trying to solve, in a roundabout way, is that an exception will be raised if `s` is of length 10 or less unless you break out of the loop early.  Why not run the loop only up to the _actual_ length of `s`, like this : `for (int b = 0; b < s.length(); ++b)...`.

Comment: Or, better yet, just forget the loop altogether.  You already know there's a `+` and you've found its location (`indexno`); you've broken out the two numbers into separate strings `s3` and `s4`.  There's no need to go looping through `s` to find the `+` _again_... just convert the numbers to `int`s, add, display, and done!

Comment: thanks Kevin Anderson for this explanation